# firefox selenium proxy setup with proxy authentication (python)

Tags: selenium, firefox, proxy, automated-tests, python-3.6

I am trying to set up sock5 proxy setup with firefox + python + selenium. I am having
**IP** and **PORT** of the proxy server. Even i added username and password it is giving pop up windows.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', int(PROXY_PORT))
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', PROXY_IP)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_IP)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", 'localhost, 127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", PROXY_USERNAME)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", PROXY_PASSWORD)
profile.update_preferences()



driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path="./geckodriver")


driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

System Information:

1. Python 3.8.10
2. Ubuntu 20.04
3. Mozilla Firefox 99.0

Answer (score 1):

That's just your proxy service, I had that same problem. I use a service called [smartproxy.com](https://smartproxy.com). You can write your computer's IP address on the website for the authentication process. If the IP address that is running the code matches the IP address you listed on their site, there will be no pop up.

I do not know the proxy service you are using but it may have an authenticated method similar to the one I explained.